# How to specify each input

Tags: jquery, input

i want to put a red bottom under the empty input only not all inputs, 
 what i need to fix  or add in this example to make this work,

```js
$(function() {
  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var myTitle = $('#title').val(),
      myLocation = $('#location').val(),
      myDescription = $('#description').val(),
      myTime = $('#time').val();
    if (myTitle == '' || myDescription == '' || myLocation == '' || myTime == '') {
      $('#title, #location, #description, #time').css('border-color', 'red');

      return false;

    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  border: none;
  padding: 4px 0;
  background: 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='title' placeholder='Add title'>
<input type='text' id='location' placeholder='Add location'>
<input type='text' id='description' placeholder='Add description'>
<input type='time' id='time'>
<button id='submit'>submit</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use each function over the inputs and check if is impty:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#submit').on('click', function() {
        $("input").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
            }
            else $(this).css('border-color', 'green');
        });
       return false;
    });
});
```

```css
input {
  border: none;
  padding: 4px 0;
  background: 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='title' placeholder='Add title'>
<input type='text' id='location' placeholder='Add location'>
<input type='text' id='description' placeholder='Add description'>
<input type='time' id='time'>
<button id='submit'>submit</button>
```

Comment: Rhanks dear, i don't know why in simple things my mind stops haha.,
i have another question please if you can help me in, 
i have input type search., i can disable it by >> prop.('disabled', true) 
my question is how to toggle this, i tried prop.('disabled', false) and removeAttr, and both of ways dont work, do you have any idea

Comment: In wich case do you want toggle disabled input search?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712794/how-i-can-toggle-the-input-statue-disabled