# How i can toggle the input statue disabled

Tags: jquery, input, disabled-input, isenabled

before i ask the question i searched on Stackoverflow about this and found out that i can disable or enable the input by prop or attr, 
but when i tried to implement this - like the following example- it does not want to toggle, am i missing something?
thank you

```js
$(function() {

  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    $('body').prepend('<div class= "item" ></div>');
    if ($('.item').length > 0) {
      $('#search').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if ($('.item').length == 0) {
      $('#search').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      //$('#search').prop('disabled', true);

    }

  });

  $('#reset').on('click', function() {
    $('.item').remove();
  })
});
```

```css
button {
  display: inline-block
}

input {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orangered;
  margin: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='search' id='search' disabled>
<button id='submit'>Submit</button>
<button id='reset'>Reset</button>
```

Comment: The code for disabling the search bar should work, however it doesn't look like it will ever be reached. You inject an element with the class `item` and then check if the number of elements with class `item` is 0. It will never be 0, since you have just injected an item with that class. You should look at your logic again, or give more information about what you are trying to accomplish with the disabling search in relation to the submit button being clicked.

Comment: Is not clear when you need to disable the div, could you clarify when do you need toggle disabled and wich one?

Comment: i am new sorry, okay what i wanted to do is to enable the search input when the body does contain the div  and when the div is removed i want to disable the input
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to check the lenght of generated divs, just play with disabled true or false depending on the click:

```js
$(function() {

  $("input").prop('disabled', true);
  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
        $('body').prepend('<div class= "item" ></div>');
        $("input").prop('disabled', false);
  });

  $('#reset').on('click', function() {
        $('.item').remove();
        $("input").prop('disabled', true);
  })
});
```

```css
button {
  display: inline-block
}

input {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orangered;
  margin: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='search' id='search'>
<button id='submit'>Submit</button>
<button id='reset'>Reset</button>
```

Comment: I was sure when i asked you about this issue that you will solve it

Answer (score 2):

For your HTML, use this:

```
<input type='search' id='search' disabled="disabled">
<button id='submit'>Submit</button>
<button id='reset'>Reset</button>
```

Notice that of [disabled="disabled"], then your JavaScript use:

```
<script>
(function() {
  var searchInput = $("#search");
  var searchAttr = $("#search").attr("disabled");

  $( "#submit" ).click(function() {
    $('body').prepend('<div class= "item" ></div>');
    if ( $('.item').length === 0 ) { // Use triple equals for exact type check

      searchInput.attr( "disabled", searchAttr );
    } else{
      searchInput.removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  });

  $('#reset').on('click', function() {
    $('.item').remove();
    searchInput.attr( "disabled", searchAttr );
  })
})();
</script>
```

This should work.